# With a standing desk, are you only supposed to stand for 30 mins at a time?

Tags: work-environment, united-states

I've had an adjustable standing desk for several months now. I stand at it all day, unless I have a meeting, then I sit in the meeting room. Recently, I learned that you are only "supposed" to stand for 30 mins at a time. But my chair is too low for my desk, even with the desk lowered all the way down, I still have to reach up to the keyboard and can't relax my arms. So it's very uncomfortable for me to sit at my desk. Since sitting is so uncomfortable, is it ok for me to stand all day? What consequences could come from that - could the desk get damaged from being in the "up" position all the time? Should I put it down at night before leaving?

Comment: You're worried about the desk or your health?

Comment: Mostly the desk. I feel fine

Comment: Who or what said that you should only stand for 30 minutes at a time? Are you experiencing or causing problems by standing for longer periods?

Comment: The company guidance is to alternate 30 min sit + 30 min stand @MikeQ, I didn't realize that until recently.

Comment: This is really a separate question but I have my standing desk all the way up and I'm only 5'8". It's the right height for me, but I've seen coworkers who are taller (who also have standing desks) reaching down to the mouse/keyboard and craning their necks down to look at the monitors. That can't be good either.

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all. How on earth could standing all day be bad for the _desk_?

Comment: @TonyK Because the desk is in the "up" position all day. It's not designed for that. It even shakes and stuff, it's shaking right now.

Comment: @dcacat Are you sure the desk is not designed for that? As others have implied, the guidance is probably for health and ergonomic reasons. It likely has nothing to do with the desk. If anything, the desk is almost certainly not designed to be switched between standing and sitting mode 16 times a day.

Comment: @dcacat Is the desk an actual standing desk? Unless you have modified or are misusing a standard desk, then yes, the desk is designed to be used in standing mode. That's the whole point.

Comment: This is not complicated. You can stand at the desk however hecking long you want. If you need a different chair, get one.

Comment: @Tashus It's a sit-stand adjustable desk.

Comment: @dcatat most standing desks 'shake' when they're in standing mode since everything is higher up, making movement and any weights on the desk have more impact.
As you say it's a sit-stand adjustable desk, meaning you can adjust it to whichever mode you like for as long as you like.

Answer (score 3):

I find it unusual that you're asking whether you should only stand at 30 minutes at a time "for the sake of the desk".  The desk will be fine.  Standing desks are typically designed to be able to adjust their height via buttons/switches on their side and can quite happily remain at whatever height you choose for as long as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments that you're worried about your usage pattern of the desk will cause problem to the longevity of the desk, I'd say reach out to the admin / facility team in your office and check if they have any specific usage guidelines.

If they don't have one, or the guideline does not mention any time period for the use, then you don't need to be bothered.

On a separate note, I'd say, pay more attention to your health rather than that of the desk. Take regular breaks (in 1-2 hours interval) while using standing desk (to walk around, stretch your legs) and ask (or demand) for a better seating arrangement.

Comment: How long do the breaks need to be? Because there's one more place I sit that I forgot to mention... (the toilet lmao) Thanks for your answer

Comment: @dcacat But are you sure the toilet is not too low?

Comment: @SolarMike lol, it's low, but it doesn't matter because I don't have to use a mouse and keyboard when on the toilet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your boss and request a new desk and/or chair that will allow you to sit comfortably as well as stand ( if you want to use it as a standing desk ).  Standing all day long does not seem very comfortable or healthy, and sitting with a desk that is too high is also uncomfortable and probably unhealthy.

An alternative would be to ask your boss to relocate you to a new desk/chair that is more comfortable.  Make sure that you let him know that your current set up is affecting your health and ultimately your productivity.

Comment: I think OP is concerned about the desk, not their own health.....

Comment: Is it unhealthy to stand all day? It's definitely comfortable - I'm used to walking all day in previous jobs (assembly plant), so standing is comparatively easy

Comment: @dcacat There is a big difference between walking all day and standing all day.  The latter is almost as bad for your health as sitting all day.

Comment: @sf02 I have to say I'm very surprised to hear that. I find it way more uncomfortable to sit and sometimes I even fall asleep lol

Comment: @dcacat Not necessarily disagree with you, but just to put things into perspective: I feel good while smoking but that does not mean smoking is good for me. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm not sure that's a good analogy because you probably still feel better when not smoking. By comparison, I feel worse when sitting. My back and butt hurt after about 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll ask for permission to purchase my own office chair, I guess. The company doesn't provide one that is high enough.

Comment: @dcacat Depending on your location, they may be *required* to provide a chair that fits you.

Comment: @Tashus They claim the current one is high enough.

Comment: "Is it unhealthy to stand all day?" See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_complications_of_standing  for more information. This website: http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/cuesitstand.html recommends to cycle through sitting/standing/moving within every half hour, e.g. 20 min sitting, 8 min standing, 2 min moving. They say they found that most people almost exclusively sit with sit stand workplaces - as you say you're almost exclusively standing, you could maybe go for 20 min standing, 8 sitting, 2 moving. Or 20 min standing, 10 min moving.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica Thanks. 2 min moving is easy enough because I do walk around to talk to coworkers, go to the facilities, get water, etc. about every half hour. 8 minutes sitting should be sort of manageable because my arms only start to hurt after sitting for 5 minutes (from reaching for the keyboard)

Comment: @dcacat: if arms hurt already after 5 min sitting in front of the keyboard (but not standing with the same keyboard), the position of the keyboard is surely wrong (not ergonomic) in some way. Check for recommendations as a starting point and then work to find a comfortable position.